# cmake of minimal_build under Centos7

Tags: c++, cmake, centos7, apache-arrow

I'm trying to compile the examples under cpp starting with minimal_build. I don't have much cmake experience. Must this be run under docker, or can it just be compiled in a Linux shell? I'm running Centos7 on a AWS EC2 instance, and I've installed cmake 3.20.2. Executing sudo ./run.sh, errors immediately with "cd: /io: No such file or directory". When I try and make what I think are the necessary changes to the scripts, I keep hitting errors.  So I just want to see is this is even possible before proceeding further.

Thanks.

Comment: What is unclear in the [example's README](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/README.md)? According to it, the simplest way is running the example under docker. Without the docker you need to run `run_static.sh` but set some variables before. (They say this way works on MacOS, but it could work on Linux too).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I did read the README. What I didn't know was that instructions for MacOS applied to Linux. I've never used an Apple anything in my life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  I recently built Arrow on CentOS 7.  With any C++ project there are going to be challenges switching amongst Linux distributions.  The docker image is a way to provide a single example that the Arrow project can verify.  You will need to adapt your Linux environment based on the issues you encounter.  @Tsyvarev is also correct, you will want to use `run_static.sh` instead of `run.sh`.  In order to do this you will need to dive a bit further into the details.

The build script has two steps.  First, it will build the Arrow project itself.  This is probably going to be the more challenging step.  [This guide](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/cpp/building.html) is helpful for this step and provides a lot more detail into how Arrow builds and what options there are.  The second step will be to compile and build the example.

Specifically for CentOS 7 one of the challenges you will face is that you will need a newer version of CMake.   I ended up building CMake from source.  If you go this route you also need to make sure that CMake is built with curl/https support.   I used the `--system-curl` option for this.

That is all I remember having to do special for CentOS 7 at the moment.  As you go about this task if you run into further, more specific, issues, feel free to ask them here or on the Arrow dev/user mailing list.

Comment: Thanks I greatly appreciate the help.  Yes, I had realized the cmake problem and built a newer version from a source download. Using the MacOS instructions ran without a hitch.